# Easiest way to distribute iOS beta app

Tags: ios, testflight, software-distribution, beta

We are working on a multiplatform project, it is a multilayered approach where we have a single codebase that is compiled and then we only replace user generated files into the final app file.

We are looking for a way to distribute our apps to our beta testers and potential clients, we looked at test flight, but it only supports iOS 8 (not good for us), also looked into crashlytics and hockeyapp, but it seems they both require to install their SDKs into your app (and due to the nature of our product as stated above) seems to be a hurdle to overcome, is there another (simpler) option where I just upload an .ipa file for distribution and that's it?

Comment: The HockeyApp SDK is only needed if you want to leverage any of the features the SDK provide. If you don't want/need any, you can still use the service for distributing your builds.

Comment: @Kerni yeah, I did try to upload it to hockey app and everything is working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using hockey-app, it is easy enough to set up without the sdk and allows to send OTA updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can try uploading the app to 
http://www.diawi.com

Then your clients can visit a link and install your beta over the air.

Answer (score 1):

For Beta Testing, 
You need to have device Token of the Testers Device, Once you had those, enerate certificate for that device as per documented on  itunes connect website.

The only thing next you need to do is to have ipa file and the certificate file generated to be shared with beta testers which they will copy in the app section under itunes and easily test the app.

Comment: Yes, this is process we are currently using and it is not optimal, as stated in other comments and answers, OTA installs and updated are what we are looking for, hockeyApp does allow to do this without the SDK so everything is good